# Remove two from inventory if custom option selected

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I've got a simple product that has a custom option. It's basically a disabled ticket with the option for a free carer ticket.

However, the issue is if the customer wants a ticket just for themselves Magento needs to remove just one ticket from stock, but if they choose to take the free carer ticket it needs to remove two from stock.

Any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Call $product->save() twice ? (ie: one in app/local and one in app/core)

Comment: An observer might be useful to check the option selected and add a second product (hidden even) to the cart when the first is added or the quantity changed for it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will take a look into both and let you know.
If anyone else has any thoughts please share.